# $\lim_{x\to 1} (x^3+2x^2-2)=1$ using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

to prove that $\lim_{x\to 1} (x^3+2x^2-2)=1$

let $\varepsilon>0$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$

we must find $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta $ then $|x^3+2x^2-2-1|<\varepsilon$

i do :

$$
|x^3-1+2x^2-2|\leq |x^3-1|+2|x^2-1|=|x^3-1|+2 |(x-1)| |(x+1)|=
$$
$$
|x-1|(|x^2+x+1|+2|x+1|)\leq \delta (|x^2+x+1|+2|x+1|)
$$

how to continue?

Answer (score 1):

$$|x^3+2x^2-2-1|= |(x-1)(x^2+3x+3)|<\delta |x^2+3x+3|<13\delta <\varepsilon $$

Provided that $$0<\delta < \min \{1,\epsilon/13\}$$

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier
(I always prefer to have variables
go to zero),
let
$x = y+1$.

Then

$
f(x)=x^3+2x^2-2
=(y+1)^3+2(y+1)^2-2\\
=y^3+3y^2+3y+1
+2(y^2+2y+1)
-2\\
=y^3+5y^2+7y\\
=y(y^2+5y+7)
$

and it's easy to see
what happens as
$y \to 0$.

In particular,
if
$|y| < 1$
(i.e., $|x-1| < 1$),
then
$|f(x)|
\lt 13|y|
= 13|x-1|
$.

Comment: what we see when $y\to 0$ @marty Cohen

Answer (score 0):

You can go the other way

$|x - 1|<\delta$

$-\delta < x-1 <\delta$

$1-\delta < x < 1+\delta$

If we assume  $0 < \delta < 1$ then

$(1-\delta)^3 + 2(1-\delta)^2 - 2 < x^3 + 2x^2-2 < (1+\delta)^3 + 2(1+\delta)^2 - 2$

$-\delta^3 +4\delta^2 -5\delta + 1 < x^3 + 2x^2-2<\delta^3 + 4\delta^2 +5\delta + 1$

Now if we assume $0 < \delta<1$ then $0< \delta^3  <\delta^2 < \delta < 1$ so

$-\delta^3 + 4\delta^2 - 5\delta + 1 > -\delta^3 + 4\delta^3 -5\delta + 1=$

$-3\delta^3 - 5\delta + 1 > -3\delta - 5\delta + 1 = -8\delta + 1$.

And $\delta^3 + 4\delta^2 +5\delta + 1 < \delta + 4 \delta + 5 \delta + 1=10\delta + 1$.

So $-10\delta + 1<-8\delta+1 < x^3 + 2x^2-2< 10\delta + 1$

So $-10\delta < x^3 + 2x^2 -2 - 1 < 10 \delta$

$|(x^3 + 2x^2 - 2)-1|<  10\delta$.

So if we set $\delta = \min(\frac \epsilon {10}, 1)$ then

$|x-1| < \delta \implies |(x^3 + 2x^2 - 2)-1|<  10\delta \le \epsilon$